# Microsoft Bot Framework and ML.NET

Tags: bots, ml.net

I am very new to bot framework and was wonder if anyone has integrated models generated by ML.Net with Microsoft Bot framework.

Any pointers to any type of documentation will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may refer to the blog

INTEGRATE CUSTOM MACHINE LEARNING MODELS TO YOUR BOT USING ML.NET

https://www.arafattehsin.com/machine-learning-models-to-botframework/

other than that you can refer to .Net Conf 2019 session - [How To Integrate ML NET with a Chat Bot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0T7P3VAh0GQ)

and here with the [sample Source Code](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/IntegrateML.NetwithBotServices) that I had Created.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating the ML.Net logic into a separate API or Azure function, and call that from your bot.

There are examples of how to create those APIs in the ML.Net samples repo here https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps

If you do really want to include the model and ML.net in your bot code, remember that the bot framework template is essentially a dotnet core API.  So you could adapt the ML.net samples to run in your bot application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to train your model and save the trained model as a zip file. Then in your bot use the pretrained model for your predictions.

Here is an example of a bot using a pretrained model for a FAQ bot.

https://www.fiveminutecoder.com/2020/12/create-faq-bot-using-microsoft-bot.html